# Replacing a string using For loop

Tags: string, python-3.x

example:

```
old_key = ''
key = '----'

for i in key:
  print(i)
  if all (i) == "-":
    print('nochange')
  else:
    old_key = old_key.replace(old_key,key)

  print(old_key)
```

Output:

```
----
```

What is the error in my approach? Since key contains all('-'), why did the old_key changed?
Am i not using all function correctly?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all` operates on an iterable. Not a single element. If you execute this code segment below:

```
for i in key:
    all(i) == '-'
```

you will see `False` printed multiple times, which is why your `else` block is executed.

Get rid of the loop and do this instead for your `if` block:

```
if len(set(key)) == 1 and key[0] == '-':
    print "Not changed"
```

What the above code does is, it converts a set out of the list `key`. Since a set in python can not have duplicate elements `set(key)` becomes just `-`. we now have to make sure that there is only one element in the set(key) and that element is `-`. The `if len(set(key)) == 1 and key[0] == '-':` takes care of that check.

i.e.,:

```
old_key = ''
key = '----'
if len(set(key)) == 1 and key[0] == '-':
    print "Not changed"
else:
    old_key = old_key.replace(old_key,key)
```

Comment: Your codes work, but i(Python beginner) don't understand the logic of the "if" statement. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

**Am i not using all function correctly?**

No, the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function will return `True` if all the parameters in the iterable return `True`. In your case, each character of your string when passed to all will return True (as strings are treated as iterable):

```
>>> all("-")
True
```

However, you will then execute

```
>>> True == "-"
False
```

Which you can see evaluates to False, causing you to enter your `else` clause, replacing `old_key` with `key`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python myself, but it looks like here is why:

```
for i in key:
  print(i)
```

`key` taken as an array with one value I can imagine, and just prints it out. The rest of the code does nothing because you are replacing '' with `key` - but there are no instances of ''